Study("somewhere")
What do the three objects represent? Find the answer below.


   *************
                              ***
                              ****
                              ***
   *********
                              ***
   ****
   ******************
                              ***
   ***
   *********
   **
   *************
   *************
   **
                              ******
   ************
   ******
   ***********
   *************
   *****
   **
                              *
   *********
                              ****
   *****
                              *
                                                         *
   **
   *************   


I couldn't line them up exactly under the image, so it looks different on mobile-friendly version. But the first column of stars belong to the first object, the second column to the second object and the third column (containing one star only) to the third object.

These objects represent ...

 ... the topology of letters in the alphabet.

The three objects ...

 ... correspond to forms with one, two or three outlines respectively. (The second and third outlines form holes in the shape.)

The stars ...

 ... encode the answer letter-wise. We can group the letters topologically according to the three groups:

  ○   C E F G H I J K L M N S T U V W X Y Z
  ⚆   A D O P Q R
  ⚇   B

 Each group of stars is the only one on the line and it belongs to one of the three groups. The last group has only a single star. It represents the only letter with two holes, B.

 The group in the middle has lines of up to six stars and there are six letters with a single hole. So one star in the middle group represents A, two mean D and so on up to six stars for R.

 Likewise for the most populated first group. It has 19 letters and the numbers of stars go up to 18. The 19th letter Z is not used here.

 So n stars in group g means: Take the n-th letter from that group. With that we get the 30-letter answer mentioned above.

The title:

 The word topology  is made up of the Greek words for "location" (τόπος) and "study" (λόγος).


Great, well done! I really wanted to use more of the third group but I couldn't find appropriate words :)

Ah, yes. Topologically, 19 and 20 are the same, though ...
